# Edit Community builder login

Tags: php, joomla3.3, joomla-community-builder

I am facing a problem.I have community builder in may Joomla 3.3.3 website which will redirect me to following url after i filled the credentials.

example.com/~crnatoday27/Joomla/index.php/component/users/profile.

I want to change login redirect to

```
example.com/~crnatoday27/Joomla/index.php/course-list/97-clinical-anesthesia-part-3 which is different for different courses.
```

In which page i have to change so that i can do changes.
Can anyone help me to sought out it.

Comment: Which module are you using for adding login details?

Comment: @emmanuel i am using community builder.

Comment: Default joomla login module has a field to set 'Login Redirection Page'. Please check if CB module has a similar field.

Comment: @emmanuel
Yes there is a field 'Login Redirection Page' in CB module.

Comment: Nice, so you could use it to set redirection page after login.

Comment: @emmanuel
Actually the thing is that i have integrated joomla 3.3.3 with moodle 2.7 There are many courses in my website.

Comment: @emmanuel
Actually the thing is that i have integrated joomla 3.3.3 with moodle 2.7 There are many courses in my website.
Each course contains a buy now button which redirect to login if the user is not logged in.If it is logged in then it would  redirect to the course page  of specific course.

Comment: If you want to change login redirect page for each course it can't be done with a setting you have to change core joomla files.

Comment: where can i find these files and please tell me name of files too.

Comment: I can't help you, your setup is complicated and can't be answered without a check in the site. You have to change redirect function of each component.